# How to generate invoice pdf in checkout page magento 1.9.1.0?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, payment-gateway, pdf

I need to generate invoice pdf in checkout page. Payment method Bank Transfer for Indian Customer. Any Idea about it?

Success page:-
/app/design/frontend/themes/default/template/checkout/success.phtml:-

```
<div >
<h1><?php #echo $this->__('Your order will be delivered over email shortly.') ?></h1>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('success_page')->toHtml() ?></div><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?><h2 class="sub-title"><?php #echo $this->__('Thank you for your purchase!') ?></h2><?php if ($this->getOrderId()):?><?php if ($this->getCanViewOrder()) :?> <p><?php echo $this->__('Your order # is: %s.', sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $this->escapeHtml($this->getViewOrderUrl()), $this->escapeHtml($this->getOrderId()))) ?></p><?php  else :?>  <p><?php echo $this->__('Your order # is: %s.', $this->escapeHtml($this->getOrderId())) ?></p><?php endif;?> <p><?php echo $this->__('You will receive an order confirmation email with details of your order and a link to track its progress.') ?></p><?php if ($this->getCanViewOrder() && $this->getCanPrintOrder()) :?>
<p> <?php echo $this->__('Click <a href="%s" onclick="this.target=\'_blank\'">here to print</a> a copy of your order confirmation.', $this->getPrintUrl()) ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('invoice/index/print', array('invoice_id' => $_invoice->getId())); ?>">Download Pdf</a>
</p><?php endif;?><?php endif;?><?php if ($this->getAgreementRefId()): ?>   <p><?php echo $this->__('Your billing agreement # is: %s.', sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $this->escapeHtml($this->getAgreementUrl()),$this->escapeHtml($this->getAgreementRefId())))?></p><?php endif;?><?php if ($profiles = $this->getRecurringProfiles()):?><p><?php echo $this->__('Your recurring payment profiles:'); ?></p><ul class="disc"><?php foreach($profiles as $profile):?><?php $profileIdHtml = ($this->getCanViewProfiles() ? sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $this->escapeHtml($this->getProfileUrl($profile)), $this->escapeHtml($this->getObjectData($profile, 'reference_id'))) : $this->escapeHtml($this->getObjectData($profile, 'reference_id')));?>
<li><?php echo $this->__('Payment profile # %s: "%s".', $profileIdHtml, $this->escapeHtml($this->getObjectData($profile, 'schedule_description')))?></li><?php endforeach;?></ul><?php endif;?><div class="buttons-set"><button type="button" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?>" onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getUrl() ?>'"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></span></button></div>
```

Comment: Do you mean after order placed?

Comment: Yes, After order placed using bank payment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create observer on order placed and then need to put one condition for your payment method and create the invoice accordingly through code.

Please see the below link which does exactly the same which you want. You only need to get invoice pdf.

https://www.atwix.com/magento/auto-invoice-and-custom-order-status-upon-checkout/

**Updated for PDF generation:**

Update you **config.xml** like below:

> app/code/community/Atwix/Orderhook/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Atwix_Orderhook>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Atwix_Orderhook>
    </modules>
    <!-- Added by Sukumar -->
    <frontend>
       <routers>
          <invoice_print>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>Atwix_Orderhook</module>
                 <frontName>invoice</frontName>
              </args>
           </invoice_print>
       </routers>
    </frontend>
    <!-- Added by Sukumar -->
    <global>
        <models>            
            <orderhook>
                <class>Atwix_Orderhook_Model</class>
            </orderhook>
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <auto_invoice_order>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Atwix_Orderhook_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>implementOrderStatus</method>
                    </auto_invoice_order>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Create **IndexController.php** at below path:

> app/code/community/Atwix/Orderhook/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Atwix_Orderhook_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
  public function printAction()
    {
        if ($invoiceId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('invoice_id')) {
            if ($invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->load($invoiceId)) {
                $pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf(array($invoice));
            $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('invoice'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').
                '.pdf', $pdf->render(), 'application/pdf');
            }
        }
        else {
            $this->_forward('noRoute');
        }
    }
}
```

And add the below code for download PDF whereever you want:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('invoice/index/print', array('invoice_id' => $_invoice->getId())); ?>">Download Pdf</a>
```

Put the below code to your **success.phtml**

```
<?php $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId()); ?>
<?php $invoiceCollection = $order->getInvoiceCollection(); ?>
<?php foreach($invoiceCollection as $invoice): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('invoice/index/print', array('invoice_id' => $invoice->getId())); ?>">Download Pdf</a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I tried above link. Get Invoice Mail. But, I Need Invoice PDF Generate button in Checkout page( Order Review).

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('invoice/index/print', array('invoice_id' => $_invoice->getId())); ?>">Download Pdf</a>

I tried place the button Download Pdf button In Success page . There not visible download option button.

Comment: Can you post you success page phtml content here in you question?

Comment: I Posed My Success page Code.

Comment: Check my updated code.

Comment: Works like a charm!. Thanks for helping. But, Payment method only get empty in invoice pdf file.

Comment: If it's working for you then tick the green mark near my answer, so that it helps others in future.

Comment: Ok, Why payment method not showing..?

Comment: Did you check if it showing fine when generate PDF from admin?

Comment: Yes,I am used Bank Payment transfer. Admin panel working fine.

Comment: It should work fine. I ll check it my local system. In the meantime try to debug it if possible

Comment: Ok. I am checking since morning..

Comment: Finally, I got Payment Information, I have copied PDF folder from below url
/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/payment/info/pdf
and pasted to my theme folder below url
/app/design/frontend/themes/default/template/payment/info/pdf.

Now, It's working fine  in success page PDF file as well as Mail attached PDF file

Comment: Great!. I have not found any solution as its working fine in my local system.

Comment: Because my theme frontend folder some PDF related view files did n't have that's why not showing...  Thanks.. Bro...

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding.